# Socket.io connects but never listens to any event when HTTPS

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl, nginx, socket.io

Long story short;
While developing my code on localhost and over http, socket.io was fine and communicated back and forth between my client and server.

Now that I implemented NGINX and added SSL proxy, socket.io seems to connect with server successfully, but no event is ever heard or "triggered".

Here's what the error.log file of NGINX shows

> 2018/04/01 15:58:45 [error] 31893#0: *772 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: .com, request: "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MA1xgon HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MA1xgon", host: ".com", referrer: "https://.com/"

Here's my server WebSocket file:

```
    import * as socketIo from 'socket.io';

let io;

export class WebSocket {

    static setServer(server): void {
        io = socketIo(server);

        io.on('connection', (socket) => {
            console.log('new connection');
            socket.on('sessionData', (data) => {
                console.log('Session Data event received');
                try {
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                } catch(e) {
                    console.log('Unable to parse JSON data', data);
                    return;
                }
                console.log('Permission ID: ' + data.perm_id);
                io.emit('CON-' + data.perm_id,  JSON.stringify(data));
            });
        })
    }
}
```

Here's my main Server class where socket.io gets attached to port 8000

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as http from 'http';
import * as cors from 'cors';
import * as Passport from 'passport';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as fileUpload from 'express-fileupload';
import {AuthStrategy} from './includes/passport-strategy';
import {WebSocket} from './includes/ws';
import {Database} from './includes/database';    

const app = express();


// Middleware go here
Passport.use('jwt', AuthStrategy);
app.use(Passport.initialize());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(fileUpload());

const server = http.createServer(app);
WebSocket.setServer(server);
server.listen(8000, function(){
    console.log('Server is running...');
    Database.connect().then(() => {
      console.log('Connected to SQL...');
      // Database.initializeDB().then(success => { console.log('success');}).catch(err => {
      //     console.log(err);
      // });
    }).catch( err => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log('error connecting to DB, make sure credentials entered are correct (secureaccessserver/Mavis/src/main/Server/includes/config.txt)');
    })
});
```

and now here's my client side trying to emit to my socket.io server

```
    pathToSocket = 'https://' + window.location.hostname + '/socket.io/';
    // I've also tried pathToSocket = 'https://' + ..... + '/server/' with same results
    socket = io(this.pathToSocket);

    terminateConnection(): void {
    const Permission = this.sessionService.getPermission();
    this.socket.emit('sessionData', JSON.stringify({
      perm_id: Permission.perm_id,
      terminate: true
    }));
  }
```

AND FINALLY my nginx configuration file

```
    server {
        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        server_name  cracenter.com www.cracenter.com;

        ssl_certificate "/root/cracenter.com.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key "/root/cracenter.key";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location /server/ {
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
        }

        location /socket.io/ {
         proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io/";
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }

}
```

Now when I run the server and launch my client (which is running on the same cloud server, just different port).. I get the 'new connection' console log successfully (from the websocket file code) but "session data event received" is never printed in the console, no matter how many times I try to trigger "terminateConnection" function inside my server code

Answer (score 0):

You have `const server = http.createServer(app);` when perhaps you should have `const server = https.createServer(app);`

Comment: I'm assuming I would have to install that as a separate dependency from non?

Comment: It is included already in node. You have to require it... `const https = require ('https');`

Comment: Or I suppose, in your case: `import * as https from 'https';`

Comment: Converting to https and adding an options parameter ` https.createServer(options, app) ` containing the .crt and .key files I used for ssl now throws error 502.. My bad its a little off from the main question, but any suggestions? The server seem to run fine, but all routes lead to 502

Comment: It seems like i'm only getting the 502 when accessing through nginx, but if i go directly to IP route works fine

Comment: Probably shouldn't post. You know? Keep it real stack exchanged.